# Converting a hexadecimal string to integer value without pre-made syntax

Tags: java, functional-programming

I'm taking a computer organization class in college. I was tasked with writing a java program that takes a user-inputted string, calls a function that converts said string into a hexadecimal integer, and then outputs the results.

The kicker is that I can't use any existing syntax to do this. for example, `Integer.parseInt(__,16)` or `printf`. It all neds to be hardcoded.

Now I'm not asking you to do my homework for me, just wanting to be put in the right direction.

So far, I've made this but can't seem to get the method created right:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Demo_Class 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner AI = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        
        System.out.println("Please input a hexadecimal number: ");
        str = AI.nextLine();
        
        converter(str);
    }
        
    
    public static int converter(String in)
    {
        String New = new String();
        for(int i = 0; i<= in.length(); i++)
        {
            New += in.charAt(i);
            System.out.println(New + 316);
        }
        
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The main step is how to convert a single character to a number representing that single digit. There's method `Character.digit`, but you can't use that. It does tell you what it mostly does. Once you know how to get the single digits, you need to combine them. Some basic math will help you out there.

Comment: *that converts said string into a hexadecimal integer, and then output the results.* is confusing. Do you want to convert something like `FF` to `255` or `255` to `FF`?

Comment: `Ints` don't really have an internal representation.  At best they are voltage levels.   Representations in any base are for human consumption.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the help you guys!

User, yes, the input would be a hexadecimal representation of a number, put in as a string. 

Rob, I've tried this concept but can't seem to figure out how to combine certain characters of a string. (my for loop is my attempt of this) 

WJS, I want to convert FF to 255 :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this, lets says you have the hex value `1EC` which in hex digits would be `1, E, C`.  In decimal they would be `1, 14, 12`.

so set sum = 0.

- sum = sum*16 + 1.  sum is now 1
- sum = sum*16 + 14  sum is now 30
- sum = sum*16 + 12  sum is now 492

So 492 is the answer.

If you have a string of `1EC` you need to convert to characters and then convert those characters to the decimal equivalent of hex values.

Try this on paper until you get the feel and then code it.   You can check your results using the `Integer` method you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

@WJS gave a good hint, I'd just like to add that the `charAt()` returns the *char*, which is encoded in ASCII.

As you can see in the [ASCII table](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/ASCII-Table-wide.svg/800px-ASCII-Table-wide.svg.png), the characters A-F have decimal values from 65 to 70, while 0-9 go from 48 to 57 so you'll need to use them to convert the ASCII characters to their intended value.

To do so, you can either get the decimal value of a character by casting to `short` like `short dec = (short)in.charAt(i);`, or directly use the characters like `char current = in.charAt(i) - 'A'`.

With this in mind, all that's left is some calculation, I'll leave that as the homework. :)

Also:

- you are looping one character more than needed, change the `i <= in.length()` to `i < in.length()`, since it's going from 0
- I don't know what that 316 "magic number" is, if it does mean something, declare a variable with a meaningful name, like:

```java
final int MEANINGFUL_NAME = 316;
```